# String to integer in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, type-conversion, nasm

I want to transfer string to integer
for example, when I type 1234 in string, it will transfer to integer 1234.
However, when I type 1234, only 12 comes out as a result and I have no idea what the problem.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .bss
string  resb    32


segment .text
global  main

main:

  enter 0,0     ; setup stack frame
  pusha

  mov   edx, 0
  mov   ecx, 0
  mov   ebx, 0

repeat: call    read_char

  sub   eax, 48
  mov   esi, eax
  mov   eax, ecx
  mov   ebx, 10
  mul   ebx
  mov   ecx, eax
  add   ecx, esi
  mov   byte [string+edx], al

  cmp   al, 0x0a
  jne   repeat
  mov   byte [string+edx-1], 0

  mov   eax, ecx
  call  print_int
  call  print_nl

  popa
  mov   eax, 0  ; return value
  leave         ; leave stack frame
  ret
```

Comment: GDB is a good debugger. Useful skill to learn is to use a debugger so you can look at memory and registers as you step through the code.

Comment: I think there are a couple of issues. You do `cmp al, 0x0a` . You are trying to test for the newline character but you have overwritten _AL_ by effectively subtracting 48 from it. So you are no longer comparing the original value returned by `read_char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by analysing, without running, it looks like your logic is wrong. On the second loop iteration, you will have `eax` equal to 1 so after multiplying it by `10` (`ebx`) you will produce the result that is equal to  the ascii value of Enter - `0x0a` (10dec).

You should move your check for enter value right after reading the char. So try to have your loop like this

```
repeat: 
  call  read_char
  cmp   al, 0x0a
  je    exit_loop // exit the loop if enter
  //code as before
  jmp repeat //jump unconditionally to the beginning of the loop
exit_loop:
   mov   byte [string+edx-1], 0
```

I think there might be some other issue as I don't see where would `edx` get incremented.

But as I wrote - it's just by analysing w/o actually running. You have the program and the debugger. Debug it! Step through the code, analyse registers and confirm what's going on as Michael Petch suggested.